# Does a superconductor conduct electricity at room temperature?

Tags: superconductivity, conductors

I know you need to cool a superconductor below a certain temperature for it to exhibit superconductivity, but do superconductors, specifically YBCO superconductors, conduct electricity normally at room temperature?

Comment: I believe it depends on the doping. check the phase diagram of the cuprates.

Comment: Did you check any source of information?

Comment: Of the articles I've read they explain the superconductive effect but not the traditional conductive effect.